# How to write my pymmysql in Python to check to see a table to see if its eof?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to check to see when an SQL table is eof here is my code below: I'm not sure on how to do this.

```
DbConnect = 'Micros'
myDbConn = pymssql.connect(*****,*****, ******,********)
cursor = myDbConn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select * from hrpersnl where p_paygroup = %s and p_ssn = %s and(p_active='A' or p_paystat='A');""",(strPayGroup,strSsn))
hrpersnl_rows = cursor.fetchall() or []

for hrpersnl_rec in hrpersnl_rows:
     for hrpersnl_rec in hrpersnl_rows:
         strName = hrpersnl_rec[87] + "," + hrpersnl_rec[44]
         strEmpNo = hrpersnl_rec[38]
         strCompany = hrpersnl_rec[25]

                           
     else:
         strName = "** Not found in Payroll **"
         strEmpNo = len(hrpersnl_rec[38])
         strCompany = ""
         strErrorCode = "3"
```

Comment: A sql table doesnt' have an "end of file"; they are unordered sets.

Comment: So there is no way I can check for eof?

Comment: There is no end of the file; it's a table, not a file.

Comment: Usually, eof means an "end of file" as Larnu said before. Tables are not files. Can you please clarify what do you mean by eof?

Comment: If the table doesn't have records in it then the else portion of the code

Comment: @Tomek For loops have an else clause in Python. [Some information on it](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause)

Comment: @gallen oh dear, you learn every day ;) thanks, I honestly didn't know that after years of coding in python. lol

Comment: The else runs right after the for loop correct?